# Использование FLTK с VSCode

Tags: c++

Помогите с FLTK, которую используют в книге Страуструпа. Скачал FLTK, собрал с помощью make install. Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>

int main() {
  Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
  Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200,"Hey, I mean, Hello, World!");
  window.show();
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Выдает ошибку

```
FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory
#include <FL/Fl.H>
```

Пытался и через VSCode и через обычную командную строку (я понимаю, что есть подробные гайды по установке в Visual Studio, но это несколько ограничивает в понимании того, что вообще происходит). В VSCode добавлял путь "C:/FLTK/include". Убирал "FL/" в заголовках. Добавлял переменную окружения. Та же ошибка. В чем проблема? (Win10)

**Ответ**
В общем, я нашел решение при помощи `fltk-config --compile xxx.cpp` и MSYS. При выполнении из под msys можно получить команду, которая выглядит так следующим образом

```
g++ -IC:/FLTK/include -IC/FLTK/include/FL/images -mwindows -DWIN32 -DUSE_OPENGL32 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -o "name" "name.cpp" -mwindows C:/FLTK/lib/libfltk.a -lole32 -luuid -lcomctl32
```

Работает и более короткая версия

```
g++ -IC:/FLTK/include -IC/FLTK/include/FL/images -mwindows -o "name" "name.cpp" "name2.cpp"... C:/FLTK/lib/libfltk.a (и далее библиотеки прописываются так же полным путем) -lole32 -luuid -lcomctl32
```

Теперь этим можно пользоваться из под обычной вин-консоли без fltk-config, которая в cmd не работает (а также во встроенном терминале VSCode), в MSYS же она работает только при условии дефолтного пути установки библиотеки (в моем случае msys/local/lib) иначе надо прописывать полный путь (страдает гибкость).

Comment: Вам следует ознакомиться с работой препроцессора, конкретно с директивой `include` (не читайте перед обедом книг страуструпа). Потом заглянуть в документацию к вашему компилятору, и поглядеть, какие опции компилятора отвечают за работу препроцессора, и конкретно за директиву `include`.

Comment: @VTT, я обозначил конкретную проблему, которая возникает у меня с одной конкретной библиотекой.